# Sublime Text Build System for Heroku

Tags: sublime-text-2, build, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I made a build system for Heroku Foreman on Sublime Text 2 (windows 8)

```
{
    "cmd": ["foreman.bat", "start"],
    "working_dir": "$project_path"
}
```

When I run this in shell, I can just break, and foreman will stop, and terminate the node process.

However, in ST2, when you use Cancel Build, it doesn't kill the node process. How should I accomplish that?

(Is this the right Q&A? I wasn't sure)